# Symfony @Paramconverter works over autowiring

Tags: symfony, autowired

I am working on upgrade Symfony 3.3 to 4.4 and almost done with it, but I have one last issue.
I enabled autowiring with default config, but whole project uses lots of @ParamConverter conversions without annotation.

Problem: ParamConverter with auto_convert tries to convert services and classes that are mentioned to controller by typehinting for autowiring (not entities).

Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/report", name="report_page")
     */
    public function report(
        Request $request,
        FileManager $fileManager
    ): Response {
        // code
    }
```

Error:

```
The class 'App\Service\FileManager' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity.
```

Service 'App\Service\FileManager' exists and works correctly.

ParamConverter config (by default 'request: {converters: true, auto_convert: true}'):

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    router:
        annotations: false
```

Doctrine config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
            # config
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            Base:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: App\Entity
```

Controller setting (services.yaml):

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false  
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DataFixtures,Entity,Objects,Repository,Utils}'
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I understand that I can set 'sensio_framework_extra.request.auto_convert' to false and use @ParamConverter annotation everywhere in controllers, but there are too many places with this conversion and I try to get default behavior, so additional @ParamConverter annotations would be extra.
Just in case: I tried to disable auto_convert and everything worked correctly (services were autowired and entities were passed to controllers).

Also I checked that I installed last available versions of packages and bundles.

Need some hints on it. Probably I missed something. I tried to find exact way how ParamConverter works by default and how it checks that class is entity or not, but it is too complicated and I decided that I dug too deep.

EDIT:
Probably I have some issue with autowiring's config and not paramconverter. But I checked `php bin/console debug:autowiring` and got all needed services as available via autowiring.

Comment: So the basic problem is that FileManager is not being injected into report?  You have used bin/console debug:container to confirm the FileManager service exists and that your controller has been tagged with controller.service_arguments?  Just trying to ensure I understand the problem.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, I checked that FileManager exists and it is available via autowiring (autowiring works correctly if I disable ParamConverter). I checked that controller is tagged with controller.service_arguments too (I provided these configs in the issue description). Problem is that ParamConverter tries to convert arguments which it should not. There is no argument for ParamConverter in controller at all.

Comment: Which is the version of `sensio/framework-extra-bundle`?

Comment: @Artem sensio/framework-extra-bundle v5.5.7. It is the latest version that is available for the current php version of my project (v7.1.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and was wondering why the autowiring did not simply work as expected, even when the respective service is correctly defined and available.

It turns out that there was an incompatibility due to our used FOSRestBundle (see [here](https://$this-%3Eem-%3EgetRepository(%5CVSF%5CFahrschuleFlorin%5CBaseBundle%5CEntity%5CMobile%5CLogEntry::class)-%3EfindOneByText(%27Test%27))). We updated FOSRestBundle and SensioFrameWorkExtraBundle to 2.4 and 4.0 respectively.
However, this required that we had to add missing ParamConverter annotations.

The problem could also be avoided by disabling the auto conversion, as follows (but it might be risky):

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    request:
        # disable auto-conversion of params to entities since it would try to convert services as well...
        auto_convert: false
```

Disabling the autoconversion is also documented [here](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html)

Comment: I've returned to this post with your answer. I use outdated FOSUserBundle in that project and probably it is a point. After all my investigations I ended up with the same as you. I added usage of ParamConverter annotation everywhere in the project with disabled auto_convert.
I still do not think that it is the best solution, but it is a working one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like symfony is trying to convert the `fileManager` like an entity.

Try moving the injected service(s) into the `__construct` method of the controller (and add the property to the controller) like:

```
private $fileManager;

...

public function __construct(FileManager $fileManager) {
    $this->fileManager = $fileManager;
}
```

and then access it in the `report` method:

`$this->fileManager`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can do so, but this project is too large to inject all services through __construct in each controller. It was just a minor example. Maybe you have any clues why symfony is trying to convert services like entities. Probably I missed something during update.